# Error : Cannot convert char to wchat_t*

Tags: c++, winapi, c++builder-xe

Im trying to get the active window title using GetForegroundWindow and GetWindowText Functions and this is my code

```
HWND hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
char wname[255];
GetWindowText(hwnd,wname,255);
```

And Everytime i try to build the project i get this error message "Error : Error : Cannot convert char to wchat_t*"

Im using c++builder xe7

So, What's wrong?

Comment: I think you will find it is `wchar_t`, not wchat_t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're building your application in Unicode-aware mode; a `char` is not large enough to hold a UTF-16 character. The type system is saving you from a *lot* of potential headache here by catching this for you. Either change to ASCII mode (easy but bad solution), switch to using wide strings everywhere (annoying solution), or use the provided macros to choose at compile time based on build parameters (even more annoying but most correct solution).

This is what this code snippet would look like with either of the above solutions implemented:

```
HWND hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
wchar_t wname[255];
GetWindowText(hwnd, wname, 255);

HWND hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
TCHAR wname[255];
GetWindowTextW(hwnd, wname, 255);
```

If you choose to build a Unicode-aware application (which you should), you must also remember to use `wmain` or `_tmain` as applicable, rather than plain old boring `main`. Because Windows.

Comment: "Most correct" solution is to use unicode everywhere. It's not 1995 any more.

Comment: Absolutely not. If he just blindly used Unicode everywhere, and then later on he or somebody else switched the text mode (imagine porting to a legacy Windows, or potentially porting forward to a new Unicode standard, or invent a plausible reason), then everything would fall apart. The macros are an inconvenience, but they are infinitely preferable to hardcoding the choice into every single variable.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Most correct is to use UTF-8, because UTF-16 is an obsolete compromise to support systems hard-coding the 16-bit codepoints of Unicode 1.0 (pre-1996). `char` does not imply ASCII; it's the only efficient representation and the rest of the world has moved ahead with UTF-8.

Comment: @Potato How do you call Win32 API when you use UTF-8?

Comment: @acwaters TCHAR is useful when you need to build for Win98 as well as WinNT. If you don't need that then TCHAR makes your code pretty unreadable.

Comment: Win32 API does not support UTF-8. You would have to convert every input string from UTF-8 to UTF-16, and every output string from UTF-16 to UTF-8.  Delphi/C++Builder did that for years (but with Ansi instead of UTF-8) until 2009 when the RTL/VCL was changed to use UTF-16 strings.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the `TCHAR` version of `GetWindowText()`.  In your Project Options, you have the **"TCHAR maps to"** option set to `wchar_t`, so `GetWindowText()` maps to `GetWindowTextW()`, which takes a `wchar_t*` parameter.  That is why you cannot pass in a `char[]` buffer.

So, you need to either:

1. Change **"TCHAR maps to"** to `char` so that `GetWindowText()` maps to `GetWindowTextA()` instead (also similarly affects every other `TCHAR`-based API function call in your code.  Use this approach only when migrating legacy pre-Unicode code to C++Builder 2009+).
2. Change your code to use `TCHAR` instead:

   ```
   TCHAR wname[255];
   GetWindowText(hwnd,wname,255);
   ```
3. Change your code to use the Ansi or Unicode version of `GetWindowText()` directly:

   ```
   char wname[255];
   GetWindowTextA(hwnd,wname,255);
   ```

   ```
   wchar_t wname[255];
   GetWindowTextW(hwnd,wname,255);
   ```